# Exact function return type without additional properties

Tags: typescript

I have a problem with return type of the `createUser` function.

```
interface IUserModel{
    fullname: string
    username: string
    password: string
}

type IUserDto = Omit<IUserModel, 'password'>

function createUser(user: IUserModel): IUserDto {
    // actually this calls a create method from a user repository
    const newUser: IUserModel = {
        fullname: user.fullname,
        username: user.username,
        password: user.password
    }
    
    /* 
     typescript does not warn me that the password property 
     should not be there
    */
    return newUser
}
```

Returning the object literal is not a solution that works for me, I would like TypeScript to warn me that there is something wrong

Is there a way to make the function just return exactly `IUserDto` without additional properties?

Comment: TS doesn’t have “exact types” that prohibit all additional properties. You can mostly prohibit specific additional properties, like `password` specifically. Would that suffice?

Comment: I think so, can you show me how? @jcalz

Comment: I will respond when I get a chance, sorry for the delay

Comment: Okay, look at [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NDJjVW). Instead of merely omitting the property, we are explicitly saying that the property must be absent (or undefined).  Does that work for you? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes, that works perfectly. If you can explain it that would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `Omit` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) merely removes a set of properties from the *known* keys of an object type.  But objects are generally allowed to have more properties than are known to their type.  Object types are not "exact" (as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#12936](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936)); if a key is not mentioned in a type, that property is unspecified/unknown, not prohibited.

Oherwise you'd never be able to use [extended interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#extending-types):

```
interface Foo {
  x: string;
}
function processFoo(foo: Foo) {
  console.log(foo.x.toUpperCase())
};

interface Bar extends Foo {
  y: number
}
const bar: Bar = { x: "abc", y: 123 };
processFoo(bar); // <-- this is allowed because every Bar is also a Foo
```

In the above, `Foo`'s definition omits any mention of a `y` property, but that doesn't stop `Bar` from extending it.  Omitting properties from a type just makes it accept *more* things, not less.

And that means an `IUSerModel` is a perfectly valid value of type `Omit<IUserModel, 'password'>`.

---

There's no way to write a type that rejects all possible excess properties.  That would require either exact types, or some sort of "rest [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures)" as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#17867](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17867), or other related features.

But you can *sort of* write a type which prohibits a *specific* excess property.  You can make it an [optional property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) (so it can be present or absent) of [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type) (so you can't easily find a way to have it be present).  This is quite close to prohibiting a property, although there are edge cases.

Anyway, that means we can write our own `OmitAndProhibit` utility type that omits a set of properties and then adds them back in as optional properties of type `never`:

```
type OmitAndProhibit<T, K extends string> =
  Omit<T, K> & { [P in K]?: never };
```

Let's try that instead:

```
type IUserDto = OmitAndProhibit<IUserModel, 'password'>

function createUser(user: IUserModel): IUserDto {
  const newUser: IUserModel = {
    fullname: user.fullname,
    username: user.username,
    password: user.password
  }

  return newUser; // error!
  //   Type 'IUserModel' is not assignable to type '{ password?: undefined; }'.
}
```

Looks good.  The compiler is unhappy with `newUser` since it has a `string`-valued `password` property, where it was expecting an optional property of type `never`.  Well, or `undefined` (unless you enable [the `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#exact-optional-property-types---exactoptionalpropertytypes), `undefined` is always allowed to be set for an optional property), but that's still pretty close.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Answer (score 0):

the type of `newUser` object should be `IUserDto`

Comment: because you have already created new type "IUserDto" to omit the "password" property from "IUserModel".

Comment: That's the problem, I'm returning something of type IUserModel, I'm looking for a way to get typescript to tell me that I can't return something of type IUserModel. In the function signature it is stated that the function returns IUserDto